# Functions that return a Mutable or Immutable variables in R

Tags: r, data.table, immutability, mutable

I think this question is related with the concept of Mutable Vs Immutable objects in R and it might be a "beginer question". I ran into this problem with the funcion `names()` and the `setnames()` function of the package `data.table`. I am sure that this is the expected behaviour but for me it was quite surprising and I am sure that is not only related with `names()`.

Imagine I have a data.table called `dt` with two columns a and b:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b= 1:5)
oldNames <- names(dt)
```

If you print `oldNames` it obviously shows:

```
oldNames
[1] "a" "b"
```

But if you chage the names of `dt` with `setnames()`:

```
setnames(dt,oldNames,c("aNew","bNew"))
```

The content of the variable `oldNames` has changed.

```
oldNames
[1] "aNew" "bNew"
```

I know that in Python this is the expected behaviour in some data types(the mutable ones) and not in others (the inmutable ones). In R, is there also this kind of dicotomy?

For me, the "expected" behaviour would be that the variable `oldNames` stores the names of the columns and it doesn't depend on the future changes of the data.table. For example, with the `length()` function this doesn't happen:

```
L <- length(dt)
L
[1] 2
dt[,c:=1:5]
L
[1] 2
```

Any link to some good information about this behaviour or explanation would be really appreciated and what would be the way to code so `oldNames` doesn't change its content after the dt modification.

Comment: You are right, it is duplicated, I thought this was an R problem/behaviour in general no of Data.Table.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is due to the implementation of data.table package. In R, multiple symbols can point to the same thing, but it usually does not cause problem since objects will be copied upon modification, for example:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- a
# To check the memory address,
# `a` and `b` are pointed to the same object since `b` does not modify `a`.
pryr::address(a)
[1] "0x1a735620"
pryr::address(b)
[1] "0x1a735620"
# Then we modify `a`
a <- c(1,3)
# We will notice that the address of `a` has changed
# since there are modifications, but `b` not.
pryr::address(a)
[1] "0x1a72f168"
pryr::address(b)
[1] "0x1a735620"
```

From my limited knowledge, the data.table package is a little special, since it will modify the object in place with some operations. See:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b= 1:5)
n1 <- names(dt)

pryr::address(n1)
[1] "0x18aeffe0"

setnames(dt, c("a","b"), c("aa","bb"))

n2 <- names(dt)
pryr::address(n2) # identical to the address of `n1`
[1] "0x18aeffe0"

n1
[1] "aa" "bb"
```

I think the data.table package did not recognize that there is a variable pointed to its name attribute, thus causing the problem. I would consider it as a bug and you may want to tag the question with "data.table".

In the current time, you can use `n <- c(names(dt))` to store the names, in this way, R will consider `c()` modified the name attribute and store it in a different memory address.

By the way, R do have mutable objects, see `Reference class` and `R6 objects`;-)

Regards;

**Update :**

See ?data.table::copy and ?data.table::setnames

To quote from ?data.table::copy:

> A ‘copy()’ may be required when doing ‘dt_names = names(DT)’. Due to
>   R's *copy-on-modify*, ‘dt_names’ still points to the same location in
>   memory as ‘names(DT)’. Therefore modifying ‘DT’ *by reference* now,
>   say by adding a new column, ‘dt_names’ will also get updated. To avoid
>   this, one has to *explicitly* copy: ‘dt_names <- copy(names(DT))’.

They are of course not common in R, data.table can do this because it uses R's C interface.

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Tumbleweed

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] pryr_0.1.2          data.table_1.9.6    magrittr_1.5        personalutils_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2      Rcpp_0.12.9      stringi_1.1.2    codetools_0.2-15
[5] stringr_1.1.0    chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
When you say "_the data.table package did not recognize that there is a variable pointed to its name attribute, thus causing the problem_" is because i this the usual behaviour in R packages?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
When you say "_the data.table package did not recognize that there is a variable pointed to its name attribute, thus causing the problem_" is this  the usual behaviour in R packages?. Actually I am a little bit more confuse with your address insight. I have checked the address of the `L` (length()) object and its address doesn't change (as it happens with the `names` object) but its value, when I add the new column to `dt` doesn't change either! So `L` points to the same position in memory but it doesn't change from 2 to 3 in value.

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, sorry I made a mistake in my example, you can see my updated answer. Use `length()` and `names()` is a little different, using `length()` is like using `c(names())`, it will do some computation and generate a new variable.

Comment: The behavior is not common, as you originally expected.

Comment: Thank you very much Marlin, your quote from data.table documentation is the answer I was looking for. I wasn't able to find it because I thought that the problem was not about data.table but of R in general.